# Register arduino board to receiver vendor ID

Tags: arduino

I am using arduino mega 2560 board installed with marlin firmware v1. Ok My questions are:

```
      1. How do I know whether my board is registered or not..?? 
         and if it not registered  then how can I register this board to
        receive USB   vendor ID...???

      2. How to flash USB firmware to use unique VID&PID..?

      3. How to stamp a unique serial number in firmware for each device..??
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. the vid & uid is licenced from arduino.cc
2. you have to falsh the 8u2 (16u2 in later version) chip on board. it is the same used on the leonardo, you just have to use the right ICMP pins. Method is exactly the same of the arduino uno [see here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,111.0.html)
3. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559264/unique-machine-id-for-arduino-project), you can wrte the serial number to the EEEPROM, but then is up to you to use it

edit: point 1. and 2. are not valid if the USB to RS232TTL is an old FTDI. In that case VID and UID are FTDI and cthe chip is closed, and you can't modify it